# HELP with XML to XML transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Am a rookie trying XSLT and XML tranformations for the first time. To start off, i tried a simple sample programs.

I expected the Output in Tree format (maintaining the hierarchy) instead i just get " KING" in single line...

What could be the problem? PS: I use XMLSpy.

Any guideline would be great full. Thanks :)

**Input XML:**

```
<ROWSET>
    <ROW>
        <EMPNO>7839</EMPNO>
        <ENAME>KING</ENAME>
    </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

**XSL used for transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Invitation>
        <To>
            <xsl:value-of select="ROWSET/ROW/ENAME"/>
        </To>
    </Invitation>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the above - if I run in in VS2010 the output I get is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Invitation>
  <To>KING</To>
</Invitation>

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only thing that I see is that you miss the closing element `</xsl:stylesheet>` in the XSL. Other than that, I think the XSL is OK, and if I use it (from Java code) I get `<Invitation><To>KING</To></Invitation>`, which is, I presume, what you expect.